# How to link files in C with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, c

Hello Stackoverflowers,

A few days ago I installed Visual Studio 2022, but I'm overwhelmed by the huge number of options available, as well as the documentation online from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/.

I've been developing an application in C that has one large file and a relatively short header file in Visual Studio 2019, and moved the code over to the 2022 version. The header file contains the various includes, defines, global variable declarations, etc., as well as the function prototype declarations. The main file contains the main function followed by the functions it invokes. However, the main file is getting too long to manage, and I would prefer to have only the main function in that file, with the functions invoked by it in one or more separate file. The problem is that I don't know how to link the files together to create an executable file. I can do this with the command line with Linux, but don't know how to configure Visual Studio to link the source files and compile them into one ".exe" file.

Rather than trying this with the application I'm working on, I created a very simple test program to try this out.

The code in the main file "main.c" is just:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func1();
void func2();

int main() {
    printf("Output from main\n");
    func1();
    return 0;
}
```

Where the prototype declarations and the include are also in that file.

The code in the second file "functions.c" with the functions is just:

```
void func1() {
    printf("func1 called from main\n");
    func2();
}

void func2() {
    printf("func2 called from func1\n");
}
```

This of course works if the functions are in the main file after the main function, but I'm unable to find how to link the code if they are in separate files. Incidentally, using an include to do this does doesn't work, and is not recommended anyway.

Do I have to use CMAKE for linking the files, and if so how to do it? If the IDE can be configured somehow to link the files in this very simple example without using CMAKE, how do you do this?

If I can link the files in this simple text, then my application can be reorganized to put the functions into one or more separate files, and keep the main function in its own file. In looking through the documentation online, including some YouTube videos, I've not seen how to do this.

All this also applies to code in C++.

Many thanks in advance for any help with this.

Comment: Just add all of the files to your solution and they will be compiled and linked.

Comment: How are you compiling this code? If you create a Visual Studio solution via the IDE and include the files in there they should be automatically compiled and linked together

Comment: The files need to be all added to your project. Putting files in the project folder does nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the various answers;  the two files are indeed in the same solution, not just in the same folder, but all attempts with build and rebuild failed with the same errors, namely that the file with the functions is not linked. Is there some configuration that has to be done?